# Why does a React input element lose focus when nested within a component?

Tags: html, reactjs, forms, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

So, I have an input element connected to the React Context API - updating the value onChange works when the element is not nested within a component. Just under the input, I render a different component that returns an input field. This input field is also connected to the context API, but the input loses focus onChange.

I understand that I could add a "key" and even an "id", but none of these solutions seems to work.

Why is this happening, and what is the best way to fix is?

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Context } from "../../context";
import { set_employee_action } from "../../context/actions";

const DashBody = () => {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(Context);

  const DashboardBody = () => {
    return (
      <div key={"table"}>
        {/* THIS IS NOT THE ACTUAL PLACE FOR THIS INPUT - BUT THIS IS WHERE IT BREAKS */}
        <div key={"LABEL_TWO"}>
          <label htmlFor={"LABEL_TWO"}>{"LABEL_TWO"}:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id={"LABEL_TWO"}
            key={"LABEL_TWO"}
            name={"LABEL_TWO"}
            value={
              state.dash.employee_form["LABEL_TWO"]
                ? state.dash.employee_form["LABEL_TWO"]
                : ""
            }
            onChange={(e) => dispatch(set_employee_action(e))}
          ></input>
        </div>
        {/* THIS IS NOT THE ACTUAL PLACE FOR THIS INPUT - BUT THIS IS WHERE IT BREAKS */}
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="dash_body_container" key={"dash_body_container"}>
      {/* THIS IS NOT THE ACTUAL PLACE FOR THIS INPUT - BUT THIS IS WHERE IT WORKS */}
      <div key={"LABEL_ONE"}>
        <label htmlFor={"LABEL_ONE"}>{"LABEL_ONE"}:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id={"LABEL_ONE"}
          key={"LABEL_ONE"}
          name={"LABEL_ONE"}
          value={
            state.dash.employee_form["LABEL_ONE"]
              ? state.dash.employee_form["LABEL_ONE"]
              : ""
          }
          onChange={(e) => dispatch(set_employee_action(e))}
        ></input>
      </div>
      {/* THIS IS NOT THE ACTUAL PLACE FOR THIS INPUT - BUT THIS IS WHERE IT WORKS */}
      <DashboardBody></DashboardBody>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DashBody;
```

Comment: Did you try to define `DashboardBody` component outside the body of `DashBody` so that it's not re-defined each time you render `DashBody`?

Comment: @JakubKosiński it works! tytytyt!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're redefining the `DashboardBody` component each time `DashBody` is rendered. You're losing the focus inside `DashboardBody`'s input because you're using `dispatch` from `DashBody` so that each time the `dispatch` is called, `DashBody` component is re-rendered and is rendering a different `DashboardBody`  component. You can extract `DashboardBody` and define it outside `DashBody` but make sure you use `useContext(Context)` in `DashboardBody`:

```js
const DashboardBody = () => {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(Context); // make sure you have your own dispatch method

    return (
      <div key={"table"}>
        {/* THIS IS NOT THE ACTUAL PLACE FOR THIS INPUT - BUT THIS IS WHERE IT BREAKS */}
        <div key={"LABEL_TWO"}>
          <label htmlFor={"LABEL_TWO"}>{"LABEL_TWO"}:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id={"LABEL_TWO"}
            key={"LABEL_TWO"}
            name={"LABEL_TWO"}
            value={
              state.dash.employee_form["LABEL_TWO"]
                ? state.dash.employee_form["LABEL_TWO"]
                : ""
            }
            onChange={(e) => dispatch(set_employee_action(e))}
          ></input>
        </div>
        {/* THIS IS NOT THE ACTUAL PLACE FOR THIS INPUT - BUT THIS IS WHERE IT BREAKS */}
      </div>
    );
  };
```